# Unable to access Postgresql database via PHP PDO

Tags: postgresql, pdo

I am in the process of switching from MariaDB to Postgres and am running into some unexpected issues.

I have installed Postgres 9.5.8 on Ubuntu 16.04.4.

From the shell, I then do the following

```
su postgres
psql
password: //enter postgres password assigned at installation
CREATE USER test;
CREATE ROLE  //psql response
CREATE DATABASE test;
CREATE DATABASE //psql response
ALTER USER test WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'password';
ALTER ROLE //psql response
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE test TO test;
GRANT //psql response
```

On my Nginx 1.10.3 server running PHP 7.0.22 I nagivate to Adminer 4.3.1 as the root user (postgres) and create the database table "test"

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."test" (
 "a" smallint NOT NULL,
 "b" integer NOT NULL,
 "c" bigint NOT NULL,
 "d" boolean NOT NULL,
 "e" double precision NOT NULL,
 "f" date NOT NULL,
 "g" character varying(1024) NOT NULL,
 "id" integer NOT NULL
) WITH (oids = false);

INSERT INTO "test" ("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","id") 
VALUES (1,2,3,'1',4.5,'2017-08-22','testing',1);
```

which creates the table "test" as expected.

Having done all of this I then write a simple PHP script

```
<?php
 $dsn = "pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;".
        "dbname=test;user=test;password=password";
 $dbh = new PDO($dsn);

 try
 {
  $count = $dbh->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test")->fetchColumn();
 } catch (Exception $e){echo $e->getMessage();}
 echo "Count = $count"; 
?>
```

When I run this script I get back the error

```
SQLSTATE[42501]: Insufficient privilege: 7 ERROR: permission denied for 
relation test
```

This appears to suggest that `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE test TO test;` is not enough to grant the user `test`all the requisite privileges to do what I am trying to do here.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about to delete this question but then thought that it might be more useful to the community if I left it there with the right answer.

The simple fact here is this - a table created via Adminer when logged in as the **root** user, i.e. postgres, will be owned by that user.  If you then go in via PHP PDO as another user you are liable to run into difficulty manipulating that table!  The "solution" is simple - just make sure that you login to Adminer as the SAME user as will eventually manipulate the database via PDO.

The fact that I am in the process of switching from MariaDB to Postgres explains why I ran into this issue - MariaDB/MySQL do not impose such a constraint on table ownership + accessibility.  However, be that as it may, logging in to Adminer as the root user can be nothing but a bad habit.

Comment: actually i have a same problem with you i am using laravel and postgress when I create table with php pdo it gives me error permission denied